# Magento 2. Where in the database is the number of customer reset password attempts

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.2.3, password-recovery

- A customer can reset his password.
- Magento tracks this password reset requests.
- Where in the DB is this information stored?

Comment: You can check in customer_entity table store all details.

Comment: Nothing about number of reset password requests there.

Answer (score 1):

The table **`customer_entity`** holds the field **`failures_num`** and **`first_failure`** to keep the record of unsuccessful password attempts.

Please check and let me know if it helps.

**Addition:** The same table also keeps the **`Reset password token`** and **`Reset password token creation time`** to identify when the customer tried to reset password last time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am interested about the number of times he requested to reset password